# How to get CSS class by name from StyleSheet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code which uses the index to get stylesheet and also css class inside that stylesheet.

```
 for (var s = document.styleSheets.length - 1; s >= 0; s--) {
            if (document.styleSheets[s].href && (document.styleSheets[s].href.indexOf("MySheet.css")!=-1)) {
                     var cssRules = document.styleSheets[s].cssRules ||
                             document.styleSheets[s].rules || []; // IE support
                     for (var c = 0; c < cssRules.length; c++) {
                         if (cssRules[c].selectorText === ".myclass ")
                             cssRules[c].style.backgroundColor = 'powderblue';
                     }
             }
       }
```

Though I get CSS class by its name in the above code I need to avoid this looping.Is it possible to get CSS class by querying it??How to do this??else some other way to avoid this looping??

Comment: There's no such thing as a "CSS class". Do you mean "A ruleset from its selector"? How would that work since selectors are not unique identifiers?

Comment: I think it would be helpful to know precisely what you're trying to accomplish, because there are a few different approaches when dealing with styles through javascript.

Comment: var someVar = document.querySelectorAll('.someClass')  will return a node list of all the elements with that class.

Comment: @Teemu — Yes. Using the code in the question for example, if you set the background on the first matching ruleset but the second matching ruleset also set the background then it would have no effect.

Comment: @lennon626 thanks.The given code will help to change the styles for already created elements.But if I want to apply the same styles to the newly created element means need to call the same code again.I want to change the style properties itself then only styles remains same since I refresh the page.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a snippet you can use to create new rules and manipulate existing rules in a stylesheet. A particular sheet is recognized by its `title`, so you need to give unique titles to those stylesheets you want to manipulate (add `title` attribute to corresponding `link` or `style` tags).

```
function CssManipulator (sheetTitle) {
    var that = this,                        // A reference to an instance
        len = document.styleSheets.length,  // Caches the length of the collection
        n;                                  // General loop counter
    this.styleSheet = null;                 // Stores the stylesheet for the instance
    this.selectors = {};                    // Stores the selectors we've handled
    this.cssRules = null;                   // Caches cssRules of the given stylesheet
    // Search the given stylesheet by title and assign it and its cssRules to instance properties
    for (n = 0; n < len; n++) { 
        if (document.styleSheets[n].title === sheetTitle) {
            this.styleSheet = document.styleSheets[n];
            this.cssRules = document.styleSheets[n].cssRules || document.styleSheets[n].rules;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Changes properties of the given selector
    this.change = function (selector, prop, value) {
        // FF knows only camel-cased propertynames, hence camel-casing the propName
        var propName = (prop.charAt(0) === '-') ? prop.substring(1, prop.length) : prop;        
        propName = propName.replace(/-([a-z])/gi, function(str, chr) {
            return chr.toUpperCase();
        }); 
        if (selector in that.selectors) { // Change the rule, if we've handled this selector before
            that.styleSheet.cssRules[that.selectors[selector]].style[propName] = value;
        } else { // Add a new rule if we haven't met this selector before
            that.selectors[selector] = that.styleSheet.insertRule(selector + '{' + prop + ':' + value + ';}', that.cssRules.length);
        }
    };
}
```

`selectors` contains the magic, it stores the index of the newly-created rule returned by `insertRule`.

**Usage**

Create an instance of `CssManipulator` for every stylesheet you want to change like this:

```
pageSheet = new CssManipulator('title_of_the_stylesheet');
```

Then you can manipulate most of the rules in a stylesheet (pseudo-elements can't be manipulated with this code) by calling object's `change` method:

```
pageSheet.change('.some_selector', 'property-name', 'value_for_the_property');
```

This method adds a new selector once, nevertheless if the passed selector exists in the original stylesheet or not. Notice, that if you change a property name like `background-color`, you need to pass "hyphen-mode" of the property name to the method.

You can develope the object further, for example `change` method could be easily changed to accept more than one property-value pair per call.

Answer (score 0):

If I understands correctly, you want to change CSS. Precisely you want to change CSS rules for a class.
To do so, and to be the most performance efficient, I would create a stylesheet with your selectors, it might be just `.selector>div{}` for example or just `.selector{}`.

```
<style type="text/css">.squerify>tr{height:60px;}</style>
```

I used this a while ago to make my table cells square (while my cells was all equal).

Then I used this code to change parameters of the class in the stylesheet.

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[numberOfSelector].style.height=document.querySelector('.squerify td').offsetWidht+"px";
```

This was the best way I could think of, but if you want, you could use a loop to search for the classes.
Send a comment if misunderstood your question.

Comment: In above code `numberOfSelector` specifies the index value.Instead of accesing it with index I need to get it with class name itself.

Comment: The way I would use this is to set this file static, then you will know which number refer to which selector.

Answer (score -1):

```
var someVar = document.querySelectorAll('.someClass');
for(var i=0; i<someVar.length; i++){
someVar[i].style.background = 'powderBlue';}
```

This will grab all of the elements with the class 'someClass' and change the background color.

Comment: This does not answer question