# Modify CSS classes using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I was wondering if there is an easy way to change the CSS classes in JavaScript.
I have gone through all other similar questions here and I couldn't find an straight-forward and simple solution.

what I'm trying to do is to set the width and height of a `<div>` to match an image that I have on my site (upon loading).  I already know the picture dimensions and I can set my CSS to that - but I want my script to figure this out on its own.

After hours of r&d (I'm a beginner), this is what I came up with:

```
var myImg = new Image();

myImg.src = "img/default.jpg";

myImg.onload = function(){

    var imgWidth = this.width;
    var imgHeight = this.height;

    document.getElementById("myBg").setAttribute('style', "height :"+ imgHeight + "px");
    document.getElementById("myBg").setAttribute('style', "width :"+ imgWidth + "px");

};
```

However, this only sets the width of the element with id "myBg".  If I reverse the order of the height and width, then it only sets the height to the image's height.
It seems like first it sets the height of the element to the image height but right after it moves to the next statement to set the width, the height value goes back to what it what defined originally in css.

I did  further research online and seems like changing the css (inserting new attributes, removing, etc.) using JavaScript is not an easy task.  It is done through

```
document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[i]  or  document.styleSheets[i].addRule
```

type of commands, but all the tutorials online and here on stackoverflow were confusing and complicated.

I was wondering if anyone familiar with document.styleSheets can explain this to me simply?

Imagine I have this class in my separate css file:

```
.container
{
    height: 600px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

I want  the height and width to change to the dimension of the picture upon loading. How do I do this?

- I don't want to define a new "style" element in my html file, I want to change the css file.
- I'm not supposed to know the image dimension before it loads to the page.
- no jquery please, I want to do this using only standard JavaScript.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't change your CSS because it's already loaded.  But you can change the values of any CSS item, including height and width with JavaScript.

Comment: instead of setAttribute use document.getElementById("myBg").style.width= imgWidth + "px"; document.getElementById("myBg").style.height= imgHeight + "px";

Comment: @durbnpoisn Actually you can [change the CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23157406/1169519) after loading, though it's not the best solution here.

Comment: I suppose I could have said that better.  In any case, there are two answers now that essentially clarified the best method.

Comment: @Teemu  your "change the CSS" link is close to what i was trying to learn. for now my problem is solved without using "stylesheets" . but i feel that i need to learn your method as well if i want to be a good javascript programmer.  thank you

Comment: @pouyazad I guessed it might be. The snippet is more general purpose, it tries to make sure, that a change made to a rule is also applied on the screen. However, like said many times here, manipulating the stylesheet is not a solution to your problem. If and when you'll find one of the provided answers useful, please accept it by ticking the checkmark nearby the top-left corner of that answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The reason only one or the other works is because in your second line of code, you destroy the whole `style` attribute, and recreate it. Note that `setAttribute()` overwrites the whole attribute.

A better solution would be to use the `element.style` property, not the attribute;

```
var bg = document.getElementById("myBg");
bg.style.width = imgWidth + "px";
bg.style.height = imgHeight + "px";
```

You can grab all elements with class `container` and apply it to each of them like this:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].style.width = imgWidth + "px";
    elements[i].style.height = imgHeight + "px";
}
```

Note `querySelectorAll` isn't supported by IE7 or lower, if you need those then there are shims for `getElementsByClassName()` here on SO.

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem. however other elements with class=container are still set to what it was defined in css.i'm good for now but(for the learning sake) i'd like to know how to hange the class container if possible using the document.styleSheets

Comment: sorry to bother you again. so setAttribute() only works if i'm only trying to change one attribute? if more than one similar to my case then setAttribute() is useless?

Comment: setAttribute can only change a html attribute, `style` is an attribute such as <div style="">, `id` is an attribute `<div id="">`. But if you use it to set style, you can set multiple CSS properties e.g. `<div style="height:100px;width:200px;">`

Answer (score 3):

If your rules start incrementing you could extract your css to a new class and switch classes:

CSS:

```
.container-1{
  /* A set of rules */
}
.container-2{
  /* A set of rules */
}
```

JavaScript:

```
element.className = element.className.replace(/container-1/, 'container-2')
```

Comment: How should I inject my new class into a page? like a page on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
var object = document.createElement('container');
object.style.width= "500px";
object.style.height= "600px";
```

You can also add values to this if you hold the dimensions in variables

```
var height = 600;
var width = 500;
```

You can increment when needed

```
height += 5;
```

Here is something you might find useful. It may offer you some insight on how you can solve a problem with many different approaches, seeing as though you are new to js.