# Accessing Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set paragraph styles depending on the screen width, basically to accommodate mobile phones. The html has several indents, both left and right. Currently they are hard coded but on mobile screens it doesn't look very good. I've tried declaring variables and then setting them depending on the screen.width, but it hasn't worked. Basically I would like something:

```
<style>
var IndentLeft = 150px;
var IndentRight= 250px;

if (screen.width <=500) {IndentLeft=50px; IndentRight=50px;}
.para {margin-left : IndentLeft; margin-right: IndentRight}
</style>
```

And then use it like this:
    `<p class="para">`blah blah

Comment: You cannot mix JavaScript with CSS like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify CSS classes using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348456/modify-css-classes-using-javascript)

Comment: Wow. hah. yeah, you can't put javascript in style tags. Looks like you could use media queries to accomplish this though.

Comment: when using javascript, you need `<script>` tags, but there's a lot more wrong with this code than just that.

Comment: This question reveals a fundamental misunderstanding of how JavaScript and CSS work. The OP needs to invest some research effort into understanding the underlying concepts before re-posting their question.

Comment: I worked around the problem by using percentage values for margins, based on the screen.width. A kludge but it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You **should** use **MediaQueries** for that.
Take a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

In your case CSS should look like this.

```
@media (max-width: 500px){
  .para{
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-right: 250px;
  }
}
```

If you want to use variables you need something more advanced, like *CSS preprocessors* ex. [LESS](http://lesscss.org) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), but first you need to learn CSS quite well.

Answer (score 0):

First, you want script tags, not style tags.  Second, if you're setting variables to string values, you need to enclose them in quotations marks.

This is untested code, but should give you an idea.  Using jQuery selectors, so you'll need this in your head tag:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the code that goes at end of body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function(){
        var IndentLeft = "150px";
        var IndentRight= "250px";

        if (screen.width <=500) {IndentLeft="50px"; IndentRight="50px";}
        $(".para").each(function(){
            $(this).css("margin-left", IndentLeft);
            $(this).css("margin-right", IndentRight);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Javascript code inside CSS code like that.

You could specify different styles for the different situations:

```
<style>
.para { margin-left: 150px; margin-right: 250px; }
.narrow .para { margin-left: 50px; margin-right: 50px; }
</style>
```

Then inside the body element (so that it exists when the script runs), you can put a scripts that adds a class to the body depending on the screen size. That way it will affect all the elements with `class="para"` inside it:

```
<script>
if (screen.width <= 500) document.body.className = 'narrow';
</script>
```