# Referencing a selector in a style block with querySelector(...)

Tags: javascript, css, dynamic

I want to get a reference to a selector in a style block so I can clone it and place it in another area of the dom in a single page app.

I have the code below that represents a simple button-like div.

```
<style>
#generate-btn {
    border: 5px solid red;
    padding: 3px;
}
#something-else {
    padding: 6px;
}
</style>


<div id="generate-btn">
    <img src="img/btn_dark_background.png" />
</div>
```

I want to be able to get a reference to the '#something-else' style within the style block but can't seem to get it. I can do:

```
 var styleNode = iframeDoc.querySelector("style");
```

Which gives me a reference to the entire style block. That makes sense, but how can I get the single selector '#something-else'? If I do:

```
var styleNode = iframeDoc.querySelector("#something-else");
```

I get a null value. Is it possible to get a reference to the selector? (Plain JS answers please, no jquery).

Comment: Perhaps not a dup, but [contains your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23153417).

Answer (score 0):

`querySelector` finds elements, not parts of stylesheets.

You're looking for [CSSOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model), which gives you objects representing the parts of a stylesheet.

Look at `styleNode.stylesheet` or `document.styleSheets`, then explore `.cssRules`.

Comment: Looks right, except support is terrible in anything Microsoft. Any polyfill out there?