# Add a CSS attribute with JavaScript using the cssText function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I managed to insert an attribute in the html tag, using this code in JavaScript:

```
document.documentElement.style.cssText = 'cursor: url("https://image0.png"), auto !important;';
```

Therefore, the result in CSS was:

```
html {
    cursor: url("https://image0.png"), auto !important;
}
```

Now, I know this is probably a silly question, but I can't find the right JavaScript code to obtain this CSS result:

```
a {
    cursor: url("https://image1.png"), auto !important;
}

.content img {
    cursor: url("https://image2.png"), auto !important;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23157406/1169519

Comment: Why are you using JavaScript to add these styles? You can just have the styles in a CSS file and link to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I read your question you would like to dynamically add CSS styles to your document using JavaScript.

You can add one or more style elements to the `document.body`. In this example it is just a string of CSS. An alternative could be to add a link element to the `document.head`.

```js
var styleELm = document.createElement('style');
styleELm.innerText = "p {color: Steelblue} a {text-decoration: none}";
document.body.appendChild(styleELm);
```

```html
<p>Hello <a href="#">World</a></p>
```